# How to properly load a Class in the Browser

Tags: javascript

I've read that it is bad practice to create global variables and functions in JavaScript because other libraries/code within a site might cause conflicts. This makes sense, so I have all of my JS code for my site inside an anonymous function like so:

```
(function(){
    var signature = MyClass();
})();
```

I have defined `MyClass` outside of the anonymous function in a separate JS file like so:

```
class MyClass{}
```

Now, I can see `MyClass` from the browser's `window` object. I assume this is considered as bad code practice. I am instantiating `MyClass` from multiple JS files. So, how should I fix this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `I assume this is considered as bad code practice.` Where did you read that? AFAIK, only global variables are bad practice.

Comment: I want to lose weight.  One way to do that is by reducing my caloric intake.  Should I reduce it to zero?

Comment: Don't get hung up on stuff like this too much. Keep in mind that if a conflict arises, it's because a script *you* included. Which means you can easily fix a potential conflict as it arises.

Comment: This is why we use es modules with [`import`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) and [`export`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export). The browser support is good enough nowadays (except IE) and you can use Webpack & Babel if you need a better support. It will clean up your code as you won't need IIFE anymore.